# C - avg of 2 arrays - always 0

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

i have 2 arrays and i want the average ,why the avg always 0 when i try to run the code?

```c
void avg(int a[], int b[], float d[]);
void main()
{
 int a[N],b[N],i,c[N]={0};
    float D[N]={0};
 avg(a,b,D);
    printf("D array is: ");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d, ",D[i]);
}
void avg(int a[], int b[], float d[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        d[i]=((a[i]+b[i])/2.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't assign values for arrays a and b, so the compiler just assumes garbage or 0 (depends on the compiler and in your case 0) so you are getting 0 in the average array.

Comment: `int a[N],b[N]` ==> `int a[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},b[N]={101, 102, 103, 104, 105}`

Comment: Aside: `c` is unused.

Comment: What happens if in `printf("%d, ",D[i]);` you change the `%d` to a format specifier appropriate for `float`?

Comment: wow thanks! i only changed the %d to %f and everything works. c is used but its not relevant to my question so..

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the code:

1. The function `avg` returns nothing and there's no reference variable concept in C that you can manipulate with the original value passed in the function.
2. `a[N]` and `b[N]` are uninitialized, that's a huge mistake.
3. Attempted to print a floating point value by `%d` type specifier.

---

**Code redefined:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

float* find_average(int[], int[]); // to return floating point array as a pointer

int main(void) {
    int arrayA[] = {2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
    int arrayB[] = {4, 3, 1, 1, 2};

    // allocating memory for the array
    float *average = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * MAX);

    // getting the values and assigning it to 'average' pointer
    average = find_average(arrayA, arrayB);

    // printing each value of 'average'
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("Average %d : %.2f\n", (i + 1), *(average + i));
    
    return 0;
}

float* find_average(int a[], int b[]) {
    static float average[MAX]; // to keep the values safe
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        average[i] = (a[i] + b[i]) / 2.0;

    return average;
}
```

---

**This will output:**

```
Average 1 : 3.00 // a[0] + b[0]
Average 2 : 3.00 // a[1] + b[1]
Average 3 : 2.00 // a[2] + b[2]
Average 4 : 2.50 // a[3] + b[3]
Average 5 : 3.50 // a[4] + b[4]
```

Comment: "The value changed for `d[i]` is forever local since that's not a static variable". No, modifications to array within the function is reflected outside as well.

Comment: @ArdentCoder The OP's code line `d[i]=((a[i]+b[i])/2.0);` (probably they supposed it's kind of taking reference.) Isn't it?

Comment: When an array is passed to a function in C, the argument receives the base address of the array in the form of a pointer (also known as *array decay*). Hence, any changes to the array elements using this pointer will affect the original array as well. [Check this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/kxub_g).

Comment: @ArdentCoder thanks for clearing the concept. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code which i have corrected in my code

Initialization of array size and array elements.

Use pointers to pass arrays to a function and also to return the array

```
#include<stdio.h>
void avg(int *a, int *b, float *d,int n);
void main()
{
    int N;
    int a[50],b[50],i;
    float D[50];
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    //initialize the length of array
    scanf("%d",&N);
    //initialize by taking input from keyboard
    printf("Enter the first array\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
    printf("Enter the second array\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
   //call by address
   avg(&a[0],&b[0],&D[0],N);
   printf("D array is: ");
   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ",D[i]);
    }
}
```

Correct form of average function.

To store results in array `D` one must use call by address method

```
void avg(int *a, int *b, float *d,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        *(d+i)=((*(a+i)+*(b+i))/2.0);
    }
}
```

Sample input

```
Enter size of array
4
Enter the first array
1
2
3
4
Enter the second array
1
2
3
4
```

This will give output as

```
D array is: 1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000,
```